# Is there a way to open Anaconda prompt, and insert a few commands that would run a python script, only by using VBA?

Tags: python, excel, vba, anaconda

I am working on a project using VBA, and have found that the best way to perform a certain function within it is with a python script (Pulling data from a web service via a user-inputted serial number, and then populating info associated with that serial in an excel sheet)(Probably the WHOLE thing should've been done in python, but I am not familiar with it, and am with VBA somewhat, so this is the path that was chosen). I have had some success with this by using pyinstaller to make the .py into a .exe, however this caused other issues, such as the script not functioning properly, and taking a while to run.

It is simple enough to run the actual python script via the anaconda3 prompt window. However, this will be used by others, so I would like it to be automatic such that, they only need to click on a VBA macro button, which then automatically runs the python script.

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need the anaconda prompt? Just run the python script directly.

Comment: I would like to be able to have the script run without the user having to manually open spyder - doing it through a command prompt seemed like it would be more accessible through VBA and would make it harder for anyone using it to accidentally mess up the python script. This was just my assumption though, since I couldn't find much on the specific issue. I found what seems like a better way though, which is to install xlwings

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. Why would the user have to open Spyder? What does Spyder have anything to do with this? I'm saying to run the Python scrip *directly from your VBA code*. I think it's `Shell( ... )`, I'm not a VBA expert, but just google it